# Tengo problemas para hacer una consulta al comparar fechas en formatos diferentes

Tags: python, python-2.7

Buenas tardes, quisiera saber si pudieran ayudarme con este problema.
tengo este modelo en donde registro las ventas que realizan cada usuario en una fecha por defecto y que esta en `datetime`

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
db.define_table('registros_ventas',
                Field('usuario', db.usuarios, label=T('Usuario')),
                Field('fecha_venta', 'datetime', label=T('Fecha de Venta'), default=now, writable=False),
                Field('codigo_venta', 'string', label=T('Codigo de Venta')),
                Field('detalle_venta', 'string', label=T('Detalle de Venta')),
                Field('tipo_venta', db.tipos_ventas, label=T('Tipo de Venta')),
                Field('destino', 'string', label=T('Destino de Venta')),
                format='%(id)s'
                )
```

ahora, con este modelo quiero realizar una consulta comparando con datos ingresados con un `sqlform.factory` así

```
data = SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('usuario', db.usuarios, label=T('Usuario')),
    Field('fecha_inicial', 'date'),
    Field('fecha_final', 'date'),
)

if form.process().accepted:
        usuario = data .vars.usuario
        inicio= data .vars.fecha_inicial
        fin= data .vars.fecha_final
new_data = db((db.registros_ventas.usuario == usuario) &
                  ((db.registros_ventas.fecha_venta>= fecha_inicial) & (db.registros_ventas.fecha_venta<= fecha_final))
                  ).select(
            db.usuarios.usuario,
            db.registros_ventas.fecha_venta,
            db.registros_ventas.codigo_venta,
            db.registros_ventas.detalle_venta, 
            db.registros_ventas.tipo_venta,
            db.registros_ventas.destino,
            left=(
                db.usuarios.on(db.usuarios.id == db.registros_ventas.usuario),
            )
        )
return dict(new_data = new_data )
```

Mi problema esta en que no puedo hacer una consulta comparando las fechas en `datetime()` con las de tipo `date()` entonces he intentado cambiarle de formato pero no he obtenido resultados, quisiera saber cual es la forma adecuada de hacerlo y el camino a seguir, alguien que me apoye :( ?

Comment: Bienvenida! Pueda que quieras mirar el siguiente [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Por cierto, ¿estás usando algún framework o librería de python en particular (ej: Django, Web2py, etc)? También podrías aclarar cuál es el motor de base datos al cuál te quieres conectar (MySQL, SQLite, SQLServer, Oracle, Postgres, etc). Puede que dichas aclaraciones ayuden a que consigas una respuesta.

Comment: Hola, estoy usando web2py como framework y potsgres como motor de base de datos :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es lo mismo una *fecha* que una *fecha y una hora*. Para ver si un `datetime` está dentro de un rango de `date`s podrías convertir los `date`s al `datetime` inicial del día del `inicio` y al `datetime` final del día del `fin`. Algo así:

```
import datetime as dt

fechahora = dt.datetime(2000, 10, 2, 22, 30, 43) # 2000-10-02 22:30:43
inicio = dt.date(2000, 10, 1) # 2000-10-01
fin = dt.date(2000, 10, 27) # 2000-10-27

inicio2 = dt.datetime(inicio.year, inicio.month, inicio.day, 0, 0, 0) # 2000-10-01 00:00:00
fin2 = dt.datetime(fin.year, fin.month, fin.day, 23, 59, 59) # 2000-10-27 23:59:59

print(inicio2 <= fechahora <= fin2)
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, ya entendí :D pero en mi caso haria algo como inicio= data .vars.fecha_inicial y de ahi inicio2= inicio.datetime(inicio.year, inicio.month, inicio.day, 0, 0, 0) ... estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Sí. Mi respuesta es genérica y no debería ser difícil adaptarla a tu problema concreto.

Comment: Genial, ya me funciono, mil gracias :D

Comment: Genial. Me alegro.

Comment: La conversión de `datetime` a `date` se puede hacer más sencilla: `inicio <= fechahora.date() <= fin`

Comment: Eso puede dar error dependiendo de lo que estés comparando. El paso del `datetime` al `date` va a depender de lo que quieras hacer.